Question on the structure of the subring generated by unity of a ring R
given some ring $R$, with unity $1_R$, I am struggling to convince myself that the additive subgroup generated by $1_R$ - that is $(\langle 1_R\rangle,  +)$ - contains the same elements as the subring generated by $1_R$.
The following is what I understand. Definitionally, $\langle 1_R\rangle\subseteq(1_R)$ as both are additive subgroups containing $1_R$, and $\langle 1_R\rangle$ is the smallest such additive subgroup. To show that $(1_R)\subseteq \langle1_R\rangle$ however I am finding much more difficult. I have first been looking at the case in which $(1_R)$ is finite. I have attempted to construct a surjective homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to (1_R)$, with $\phi(n) = 1_R + 1_R + \dotsc + 1_R$ where $n$ unities are added together. In the case that $|(1_R)| = ord_{1_R}(1_R)$ (where by order I mean additive order or the number of $1_R$s which must be added together to get $0_R$), it is clear that $\phi$ is onto. I have thus been trying to find a contradiction when assuming unity has additive order less than $|(1_R)|$ in $(1_R)$. Intuitively I want to be able to say that for some $a \in (1_R)$, because $a = 1_Ra$, we have that $a$ is equal to $1_R$ being added $a$ times, but in a ring of functions for instance, this makes no sense (e.g. $f$ added to itself $f$ times?). I would be grateful for any advice on whether my approach is suitable and if not what else I should be thinking about.
Thanks.

I would just show that $\langle 1_R \rangle$ is closed under multiplication.

The additive subgroup is ${n\cdot 1_R: n\in\mathbb{Z}}$. You need to check this is a subring. Start by showing that for $m,n\geq 0$ (then it's easy to generalize to negative integers) we have $(m\cdot 1_R)\cdot (n\cdot 1_R)=mn\cdot 1_R$. If you want to do it formally, fix $m$ and prove this by induction on $n$.

Thank you. I now understand the needed argument to show that $<1_R>$ is a subring. However, I am confused by the given expression for the additive subgroup. I understand this group to be $1_R$, added to itself in as many ways are distinct. Is $n \cdot 1_R$ just different notation to mean the same thing @Mark?

@Rohan Yes, for $n\geq 0$ the notation $n\cdot 1_R$ means adding $1_R$ to itself $n$ times. Similarly, $(-n)\cdot 1_R$ is adding $-1_R$ to itself $n$ times.
